# Match value in column C to data in column A and return all data of column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with (for example) 4 columns and I want to search column A for a value mentioned in column C and show in column D all the results that were found in column B separated by a `;` and a space.

I got this partly working with the following formula:

```
=IF(C3<>"";TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IF(($A$2:$A$6=$C2);$B$2:$B$6;""));"")
```

The thing is, this formula doesn't show any results when the search criteria   is not 100% matching.

The following doesn't work:

```
=IF(C2<>"";TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IF(($A$2:$A$6=("*"&$C2));$B$2:$B$6;""));"")
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(C2<>"";TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2;$A$2:$A$6));$B$2:$B$6;""));"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works great. is it also possible to filter out duplicates in the same cell?

Comment: Not sure what duplicates you're getting. Maybe ask a new question and provide sample data that returns duplicates?

Comment: In the picture shown above, is each cell in column B unique. if you change the value in cell B4 to 1, the current formula in D2 will show 1; 1; 4. I want the formula to show only unique records, so the results should be 1; 4.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `Unique` function?

Comment: no it shows and error when i try to use that function